# Concurrency issue using Resteasy client over SSL

Tags: java, http, rest, ssl, resteasy

When running Resteasy client (version 3.0.6.Final) concurrently and sufficiently fast, I always get:

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1977) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1093) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:533) ~[httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:401) ~[httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178) ~[httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304) ~[httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863) ~[httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) ~[httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57) ~[httpclient-4.3.1.jar:4.3.1]
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:283) ~[resteasy-client-3.0.6.Final.jar:na]
... 20 common frames omitted
```

Such issue never appears in regular calls (low concurrency), so the SSL initialization should be fine:

```
// load the certificate
InputStream fis = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/to/redlink-CA.crt");
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(fis);

// load the keystore that includes self-signed cert as a "trusted" entry
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType()); 
keyStore.load(null, null);
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyStore.setCertificateEntry("CA", cert);
tmf.init(keyStore);
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

// build the rest client
ResteasyClientBuilder clientBuilder = new ResteasyClientBuilder();
clientBuilder.sslContext(ctx);
```

So I'm running out of ideas how to find the source of this issue, which is very difficult to debug.